# Firestore Query using a map of values does not invoke listener when the map is modified

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

As "collection group query" is still not implemented on Firestore I am using a map of values as a workaround. Here is the structure:

```
/chat/[room_id]/
                 user[ user_id ] = true
```

The query is something like:

```
db.collection( 'chat' )
  .doc( room_id )
  .where( 'user.' + user_id, "==", true )
  .onSnapshot( ... )
```

They query works perfectly, but if a "user-map" adds or remove the "user_id" field, the listener (onSnapshot) is not called. On Firebase console the value flashes indicating that a change was made.

According to the documentation maps are automatically indexed, so it should not be a indices problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Cloud Firestore now supports collection group queries: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) we can see that:

> Queries on multiple fields with range filters require a composite
>   index. Unfortunately, this is not possible with the approach shown
>   above. Indexes must be defined on specific field paths. You would have
>   to create an index on each possible field path (such as
>   `categories.cats` or `categories.opinion`) which is impossible to do in
>   advance if your categories are user generated.

The "approach shown above" refers to the case where you are performing a compound query with a map of values (same example as yours). The solution they propose is to

> encode all of the information for the query into the map values

Although not ideal, it might be useful for certain cases.

Comment: I don't see a query on multiple fields here. So I'm not sure how this applies.